# How to extend module in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am writing a speech recognition program. I'm using `@google-cloud/speech` as the recognition lib.

Well, the language I am using is Typescript (tsc version 3.5.3) and the problem here is that there is no `@types/google__speech`.

As soon as compiler recommends me to (otherwise) define it by myself I would do it. I decided to follow the official documentation, but only implementing things that I will need now. So the code I have:

```
declare namespace google.speech {
    export namespace types {

        interface SpeechClientOptions {
            keyFilename: string;
        }

        interface StreamingRecognitionConfig {
            config: RecognitionConfig;
            singleUtterance?: boolean;
            interimResults?: boolean;
        }
    }

    class SpeechClient {
        public constructor(opts?: types.SpeechClientOptions);
        public streamingRecognize(config: types.StreamingRecognitionConfig): NodeJS.WritableStream;
    }
}

declare module "@google-cloud/speech" {
    export = google.speech;
}
```

I have shortened a code above, removing enums and other interfaces that I have declared in the same way in `types` namespace.

As far as I understand (read as want to) I 1. Declare a typings for `@google-cloud/speech` and 2. also extend the module with extra type definitions. That is what I meant to do really.

And here comes the problem. 
I try to import my newly created types (remember, InteractionType, etc. are defined and they are enums):

```
import { types } from "@google-cloud/speech";
const { InteractionType, MicrophoneDistance, RecordingDeviceType } = types;
```

Error:

```
interactionType: speech_1.types.InteractionType.VOICEMAIL,
                                            ^   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'InteractionType' of undefined
```

I have read several similar questions but all the stuff mentioned there did not help me. I think I miss something really basic.

So, can anyone tell me what is possibly going wrong?

I suppose I should post my tsconfig.json as well:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "build/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I build project with `tsc --build tsconfig.json` and my `node --version` is `v12.5.0`.

Project structure:

```
./
 | - build/
 | - node_modules/
     | - @google-cloud/
         | - ...
 | - src/
     | - @types/
         | - @google-cloud__speech/
             | - index.d.ts
     | - app.ts
 | - package.json
 | - tsconfig.json
```

If I miss any valuable information please tell me, I will add it.